# Which LEGO part can build this?

Tags: part-identification

[image: Picture of moko's mech MOC, with a specific part circled in blue]

This is moko’s MOC mech, I want to know what the part highlighted within the blue circle is. I think it’s not 3638...

Answer (score 21):

Neither Brickset nor Bricklink knows of a part with number 3638, so it's unclear what you do not think it is. But I believe it's [3937 Hinge Brick 1 x 2 Base](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=3937#T=C) + [3938 Hinge Brick 1 x 2 Top Plate](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=3938#T=C).

[image: Assembled hinge]

Comment: Yes, seems like it. Notice that it looks as if there is a notch in the side wall of the part - but I believe this notch is a consequence of this part + another brick right next to it. What is the other brick isn't clear but it should be something with a bit smaller height.

Comment: Just 1/2 a circle? Mudguard

Comment: There are no half-circles in the blue circle on the picture, so that's not what the question is about, but I guess the blue part around the yellow part in the bottom left of the picture is a mudguard.

Comment: It looks like a 2x2 top plate rather than a 1x2 to me, though that's nit-picking: [2x2 link](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=6134)

Answer (score 8):

As [Henrik supports the community’s fine answer indicates](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/a/18527/2360), this is definitely [3937 Hinge Brick 1×2 Base](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=3937#T=C) + [3938 Hinge Brick 1×2 Top Plate](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=3938#T=C), with both parts in white. The fact that these parts, as well as all the bricks around it, are white, and the photo is blurry and somewhat overexposed (at least for seeing details in all that white), makes this somewhat more difficult to see than it should be, so I traced out the 3937 piece in the photo to make it easier to see:

[image: Photo from the question with red lines drawn within the blue circle to highlight the shape of part 3937]

Note that this is in a SNOT configuration, with the base connected to studs that are above and behind it, pointed down and to the front of the model. This also matches the blocks on the top of the crest, which are pointing the same way. It may be easier to see the orientation of this section by looking at the end of that column, which is a [54200  Slope 30 1 x 1 x 2/3, a.k.a. the “cheese slope”](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=54200#T=C). That’s pretty clearly visible in the photo, (mostly) filling in the gap that would otherwise exist in the corner (and preventing the 3937+3938 hinge from opening fully). It’s not clear from the photo what pieces were used to achieve this orientation; there are several options.